# Getting data loader error while uploading data

Tags: data-loader

We are uploading bulk data through Apex Data loader,but getting an error message like -' FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded'.Can you please advise me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the short-term, reduce the size of your batches (in Data Loader, Settings > Settings > Batch Size) in order to reduce the number of records processed at once. You will need to play with different values until you no longer get timeout errors. If you get to a batch size of 1 and it still fails, you may have an infinite loop that needs to be diagnosed.

In the long-term, you'll need to use profiling (in Salesforce, "Your Name" > Developer Console, then Debug > Change Log Levels > Add/Change, and set profiling to FINEST), then run a few batches that fail and read the debug logs. They'll include information about which functions are taking the longest. You may need to uninstall packages and/or optimize your own organization's logic.